# Search by PHP Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get some variables from a form and i will use those variables to make a search bar for example:

```
$var=$_POST['var']
```

I want to put this variable in a request like this:

```
$SQL = 'SELECT * FROM Table ORDER By $var'
```

Any suggestions please? How can I transform this request to a dynamic request?  thank you :)

The code is:

```
<form>
     <lable for="Variable">
     <input type ="text" name="variable" placeholder="Search by : ">
</form> 
<?php
    $variable = $_POST['variable'] 
    sql = 'SELECT * FROM Total ORDER BY $variable'; 
?>
```

Comment: and what is value of `$variable`? just use for order by only?

Comment: To start with, form method="POST"

Comment: what is your definition of _"a dynamic request"_ ?

Comment: Do make an effort to complete this example. What you're trying to do will work once implemented, i.e., add a submit button to the form, make the method POST and execute the SQL you are mentioning if you have postdata available.

Comment: @Khaled Claude Boussoffara : Some feedback is always nice. I know you are new, but the more information you provide the best it is for us to help you.

Comment: this form is completed i wouldn't post a lot of code my question is how to make this request dependent from the value posted by the user

Comment: Your question is confusing. The text says you want to make a search bar, but the query uses the search field for ordering, not searching. Which are you really trying to do?

Comment: when a user enter a word  all the article in the index page take the order by this word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first,

use `method="POST"` and `action="file.php"` (but `action` is not strictly needed, in some cases like processing by AJAX)

```
<form method="POST" action="file.php">
   <lable for="Variable">
   <input type ="text" name="variable" placeholder="Search by : ">
</form>
```

At second you need sanitize input taken from form (it means, you have to eliminate anything that would harm your pages - with this [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or else layer can help).

At third, you need to rewrite

```
sql = 'SELECT * FROM Total ORDER BY $variable'
```

to

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM Total ORDER BY $variable"
```

or

```
sql = 'SELECT * FROM Total ORDER BY '.$variable
```

because else used variable would be used as is written, instead its content (given by form).

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and for [order by](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html) review.

your select query would be

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable ORDER BY DATABASE_FIELD;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're new it would be wise to embed some good practices from the start. Documentation for reference would be [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

An example PDO tutorial can be found on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp), along with a [tutorial on handling form data with PHP](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp).

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a simple search

PHP:

```
<?php

$search = $_POST["search"];

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `profile` WHERE `email`='$search'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="profile.php" method="post">  
<input type="text" name="search"><br>  
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Glad to help :)
If you found it useful please accept my answer